# Postgresql add values to a column with a for loop (on Python)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I've added a new column to my postgresql table.
Now I want to add values to this new added column. 
The only commands I found allow adding values but not in chosen rows of the column. 
What I'm tryin to have is:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT Column_name FROM Table_name')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD NewColumn_name type')
for row in rows:
     #Here I want to have a commands that adds a value (result of a function: func(row)) to every row of the new column, one by one something like: 

     NewColumn_name[i] = func(row)
     i = i+1
```

Comment: What is the primary key or unique column?

Comment: What does `func` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute `UPDATE` statements in your loop's body. Instead of this:

```
 NewColumn_name[i] = func(row)
```

try something like this ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)):

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE Table_name SET NewColumn_name = %s WHERE id = %s', (func(row),row[0]);
```

Assuming the Table_name's first row is a primary index.

Comment: It actually worked at the beginning ( I printed the new added values) bit while it was running it ends with an error : **SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected with python and psycopg**

Comment: I suppose it can't be due to memory problem because they're not more than 10000 new values to add with the UPDATE querry !

Comment: Did your read this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130305/postgres-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected-with-python-and-psycopg

Comment: Yep I did .. and I think I still have to add free more space. Does adding values like this take more space than adding them directly from a csv file?
Because I dropped the whole table that normally contains 5 rows and replaced it with one with only 2 rows ... and with the first I don't get any memory problems

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `update`?

```
update table_name
    set column_name = ?;
```

Fill in the `?` with the value you want (using a parameter is much preferred to munging the query string).