# Unable to apply Django migration in Postgres DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

In Django app, I'm using Postgres DB.
I have two tables where one of them has **76** million records and the other **8.2** million.

I have created a new migration file where in I'm adding a new column to a table in an app and setting default value to **0**.

My database is hosted on **Ubuntu EC2 instance** which has **RAM** of **8 GB**.

When I try to apply the migration using `python manage.py migrate app_name migration_file_name`, it's throwing below error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

I have gone through this solution [Postgres SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected with python and psycopg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130305/postgres-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected-with-python-and-psycopg/43630509#43630509) But not sure if it's memory issue or something else.

```
Python: 2.7.12
Django 1.11.15
Ubuntu: 18.04
Postgres DB: 10.7
```

What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query might too large - too many operations. This causes the system to run out of memory.

Answer (score -1):

Adding new column with default value trig a table reconstruction. To avoid that with big table, you can create you migrations in 3 times.

- Firstly, Create a migration file to add NULLABLE column without default value.
- Secondly, Create an empty migration that fill this new empty value with excepting default value to all instance with null=True
- Thirdly, Create a migration that define your column is not nullable with a defaut value