# RDS PostgreSQL - what is the maximum value and default value for keepalives_idle?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS PostgreSQL.

According to this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html), `keepalives_idle` can be used to control the number of seconds of inactivity. It says, "A value of zero uses the system default."

Q1. What is the system default?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63130830/3480376), some databases require `keepalives_idle` less than a maximum value.

Q2. What would be the maximum value for `keepalives_idle`?

I can't find any resources to answer these two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client side setting while connecting to PostgreSQL database. This doesn't have to do anything with AWS RDS. As the document says, this parameter is only valid for connections made via keeping the setting `keepalives` to 1 (which is the default).

Since the doc says:

> It is only supported on systems where TCP_KEEPIDLE or an equivalent socket option is available.

both `tcp_keepalive_time` and `tcp_keepidle` should be used for this parameter whichever is available in the OS.

The system default is the value at `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time`. Just do:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

which should be 7200 (seconds). Some systems also use `tcp_keepidle` which is equivalent to `tcp_keepalive_time`. For example, IBM AIX which is a UNIX based OS uses `tcp_keepidle` (whose default value is also 7200 seconds). To see which systems use which value for sending the probe after the connection is idle, you can refer [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdse/6.4.0?topic=planning-tcpip-settings).

According to the [`Linux Man`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) page, /proc interfaces are used to set system-wide TCP parameter settings. So, setting `tcp_keepalive_time` either by:

```
$ echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

or modifying the values in `/etc/sysctl.conf` would modify the setting system wide. While `TCP_KEEPIDLE` is used while writing any user specific socket communications that can be set using `setsockopt` function call.

You can optionally also choose to set this parameter manually while making connection to a PostgreSQL database. If using `psql`, you can do:

```
$ echo "SET tcp_keepalives_idle = 42;" >> ~/.psqlrc
```

and then proceed with psql connection. You can see a variety of options [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/169334/90913).