# Cors issue on GCP Cloud Run with GoLang

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-run

I have COR's enabled on the backend and locally it works fine. I added the frontend URL via an environmental variable. However, when I get on GCP several 302 Redirect and eventually fails after a few seconds. Even when I add '*' it doesn't work!

I do not see the `Origin` nor the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`headers and what I am thinking is maybe `if origin != "" {` is in fact empty and the rest is never set. However locally the Origin header is there. How can I do this on Cloud Run?

Here is the method in the middleware that is handling the CORs

```
func (app *MiddleWare) EnableCORS(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(r.Context())

        w.Header().Add("Vary", "Origin")

        w.Header().Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Method")

        origin := r.Header.Get("Origin")

        if origin != "" {
            clog.InfoCtx("origin", log.Ctx{
                "origin": origin,
            })

            for i := range app.cfg.Cors.TrustedOrigins {
                if origin == app.cfg.Cors.TrustedOrigins[i] {
                    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)

                    clog.InfoCtx("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", log.Ctx{
                        "origin": origin,
                    })

                    if r.Method == http.MethodOptions && r.Header.Get("Access-Control-Request-Method") != "" {

                        clog.InfoCtx("Access-Control-Request-Method is not empty", log.Ctx{
                            "value": r.Header.Get("Access-Control-Request-Method"),
                        })

                        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE")
                        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type")
                        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

                        return
                    }

                    break
                }
            }
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Nginx config on the frontend.

```
     location ~ ^/(v1)/ {
         error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_pass http://api;

         add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin" always;

         expires off;
     }
```

[image]

------ Update 1 ---------

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624701/why-cant-1-cloud-run-service-client-connect-to-another-backend-cloud-run-se) it appears I need to use a serverless VPC on the frontend. The request to the API is made by browser and now it should be going through the serverless VPC. However I still have the same issue and I am thinking I need to add the vpc's hostname to the allowed list on the API but I cannot find it, just the IP range.

Comment: Trying to capture the request headers in your pod to see whether `Origin` header is there or not. Or just print all headers to check the existence of `Origin` header that your CORS handler might need.

Comment: BTW, the preflight request sent from you browser also means a lot. Make sure you are actually in an CORS scenario.